# How to add the default generated javascripts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I generated a Rails 4 application with the `--skip-javascripts` parameter having misunderstood what those javascripts were:

```
rails new Myapp --skip-javascripts
```

I'd now like to add those javascripts that I skipped into my Rails application (the ones that end up in `app/assets/javascripts`). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Rails app and copy over those files.

Comment: That certainly gets them into the filesystem, but the application doesn't include them when rendering pages.

Comment: did you include any missing gems? did you transfer over the manifest?

Comment: If I were missing gems it would throw an error when I run the rails server. As for the manifest, are you referring to `app/assets/application.js`? I did add that, to no effect.